# Adding To: header to incoming mails using hMail server

Tags: email, smtp, smtp-headers

I have just enabled plus-addressing with my instance of hMailServer. Now, whenever I sign up for an online service, I can *easily* provide a unique email address for that service. This is part spam-prevention and part curiosity. If the unique email address I provide starts being spammed, I can simply turn it off **and** know exactly where my address was leaked from.

Now, the problem arises in that some incoming spam emails do not specify a `To:` header, making it impossible (without reading the SMTP logs) to find out which email address is the intended recipient.

I know that hMail supports scripted extensions for mail processing (See [OnAcceptMessage](http://www.hmailserver.com/documentation/latest/?page=scripting_onacceptmessage) for example).

---

So then, with hMailServer; In the case where the incoming mail is from an unauthenticated sender, is it possible to add the parameter of the SMTP command `RCPT TO:` as a header to the incoming email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're erroneously using the message *headers* when you should be using the message *envelope*.  The `To:` header is entirely irrelevant for figuring out the message recipient — as should have been obvious from the fact that those messages entirely without `To:` headers were successfully routed to you.  [The hMailServer documentation even discusses this.](http://hmailserver.com/documentation/v5.3/?page=information_recipients)

It moreover tells you about [the list of recipients for a message](http://hmailserver.com/documentation/v5.3/?page=com_object_recipients) before it is delivered.  It furthermore tells you [where the setting is](http://hmailserver.com/documentation/v5.3/?page=reference_protocolsmtp) for [the conventional `Delivered-To:` header](http://cr.yp.to/proto/mailloops.txt) that conventionally records envelope recipients after messages have been delivered and their envelopes discarded.